# Conditionals: WILL or WOULD -when it is happening, which one to use?

Tags: sentence-construction, conditional-constructions

Let's say you and your *girlfriend* are dating. **Suddenly**, she asked *you* if you love her, then you immediately blushed.

> Girlfriend: Do you love me?
>
> You: (blushing) Of course I do, I **won't** be blushing if I **dont.** (1st conditional)

Or

> Girlfriend: Do you love me?
>
> You: (blushing) Of course I do, I **wouldn't** be blushing if I **didn't.** (2nd conditional)

When using conditionals, it depends on the context of what you are trying to say, moreover, sentence1 & sentence2 in this situation that I have given is what I am not sure which one to use. Conditionals are usually hypothetical, but here, it is **still happening.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first sentence describes a conditional situation, but it is not an example of a [conditional mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_mood). "Will" is usually used for the future tense.

> I will not be blushing if I do not love you.

This means that at some point in the future the speaker either will or will not be blushing, which will depend on whether the speaker loves her. This does not seem to fit the context you have described, but it could be a grammatically correct sentence. Perhaps the speaker is telling the girlfriend what signs to look for when they next meet.

> I would not be blushing if I did not love you.

This means that the current blushing is a consequence of the speaker's love for her. This is the correct sentence for the context you have described.

You can read more about "will" and "would" on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_modal_verbs#Will_and_would).

Comment: Yeah, you nailed it and seems like I got it, something that the ''would'' in the example is the past tense of ''will''.